# How to zgrep and then gzip multiple files individually?

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, grep, gzip

I have the following code which searches for a term in multiple files (`file1.json.gz, file2.json.gz, etc etc`) using zgrep, and then using gzip it saves the output into a single file:

```bsh
zgrep -i 'help' /input/path/*.json.gz | gzip > /output/path/help_file.json.gz
```

This works well, but is it possible to change this so that the files in `/input/path/` are handled individually? I.e, `file1.json.gz` becomes `file1_filtered.json.gz`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but with a little script :

```
for f in /input/path/*.json.gz
do
  zgrep -i 'help' "$f" > "/output/path/$(basename "$f" .json.gz)_filtered.json.gz"
done
```

Here, `basename` get rid of the path, and also the .json.gz suffix, which is replaced by what you want.